# How to calculate all possible results of a N-sized yes/no test?

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to calculate the possible results of a test with 70 questions. They're all bools. How to do that and how many calculations they have to be done.

Comment: Your result is 2^70, assuming they're independent.

Comment: They're independent. But can you show example how to calculate it?

Comment: And the generalization is: **2^N** paths exists, given that the number of boolean questions is N. From someone over 1000 points, I wouldn't have expected such a question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you need to run though every combination of 70 true/false values, that's around 2^70 = 1.18e21 = 1.18 sextillion combinations. If you could do one per clock cycle, a 4-core machine at 3 GHz would take 3000 years to compute all solutions. If you printed each result on 0.1mm thick paper, at 50 lines per page, the stack of paper would be over a trillion miles high (and you might think about the fact that a single mile-high stack of paper has over 16 million sheets, weighs 72 tonnes and takes over 1000 trees to make).

I would reconsider the method of analysing this problem.

Comment: `+1` for the totally useless math..

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to do this in a loop or recursively.

the order of **2<sup>70</sup>** calculations have to be done, considering that's the number of possible tests.

OR maybe just **70** if you don't care about individual paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to get the amount of bools that were true, assuming they are stored in an array, loop through them.

```
int score = 0;
for(int c = 0; c < boolArray.Length; c++)
{
    if(boolArray[c])
    {
        score++;
    }
}
// (Now you have the score)
```

I'm not sure this exact code will work as I am not very familiar with c#, but you should get the point.

If you mean you want all the possibilities that the test could give you, its 2 ^ 70
(2 because a bool only holds two values, 70 because there are 70 bools).

Answer (score 0):

Well, each result can be true or false, so there are 2^70 results altogether. (It's awfully a lot!)

If you really want to enumerate through all the results, you can do the following:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<bool>> EnumerateResults()
{
    var curr = new List<bool>();
    for (var idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++) curr.Add(false);
    while (!curr.All(v => v))
    {
        var idx = 0;
        // add one with carry
        while (curr[idx]) // no index OOB, because of while condition
        {
            curr[idx] = false;
            idx++;
        }
        curr[idx] = true;
        yield return new List<bool>(curr); // clone
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. You're dealing with a N-sized binary number. For example, a 4 question test, has 16 possibilities

0000
0001
0010
0011

0100
0101
0110
0111

1000
1001
1010
1011

1100
1101
1110
1111

For N, it's just 2^N